# Determine the actual interface via which a client connected if listening on INADDR_ANY?

Tags: c, sockets

In a scenario, where I am listening on a TCP port via `INADDR_ANY`, and get a client connection, and now want to accept UDP packets from that connection, how can I determine the actual IP address of the interface that routes to that client to bind the UDP socket to that interface instead of INADDR_ANY? `getsockname` of my listening socket would return `INADDR_ANY` as far as I understand, so is there some other socket API that can provide this info? Or must I manually keep a route table where I try to resolve each client by connecting to it (or send ARP on all interfaces and see which one resolves the address?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have accepted the connection, you can get the local address of the new (connected) socket that `accept` returned, with the `getsockname` function.

Comment: Ok, I always though that gives the client IP not the local one, will try if my believs have been an illusion :D

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis To get the remote address details you use the `getpeername` function.

Comment: Ahh, I found my source of confusion, `accept` returns peer address, but `getsockname` most likely then gives me what I need (accept and upvote incoming:D)